# UI get value function not work in Document App

Tags: google-apps-script

looks like the e.parameter.name method to get text box value is not worked on document UI,
For example, in main UI

=============================================================

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(455).setTitle('My UiApp Sidebar');
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
var textBoxA =   app.createTextBox()
                    .setId('textBoxA')
                    .setName('textBoxA').setTag('textBoxA');


var clickButton=app.createButton("Paste")
                   .setId("PasteTest")
                   .addClickHandler(pasteHandler) 


var pasteHandler = app.createServerChangeHandler('readTextbox');
pasteHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);

panel.add(textBoxA);
panel.add(clickButtion);
app.add(panel);
DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(app);
```

======================================================================

then in event handler

```
readTextbox(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
var boxValue=e.parameter.textBoxA;
  return app;
}
```

the boxValue return undifined, the e.parameter.textBoxA_Tag also not work, i put the e.paramter in log, not textBoxA in there.

It is works fine in Spreadsheet UI, looks like not support document UI very well

Comment: Pls add the lines hidden under `$button and click handler$`in your code. I'd rather think that you simply forgot to add the textBox as callback element.

Comment: I added all the code, the potin is, the code is work fine in spreadsheet, but not in document

Answer (score 1):

try putting things in the right order and it will work.

[test doc here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BzHfzpGv53ockR5Q4MnYMnOA0HVtsTQlPaeCraYUIIE/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function xx(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(455).setTitle('test sideBar with textBox');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','25px')
  var textBoxA =   app.createTextBox()
                    .setId('textBoxA')
                    .setName('textBoxA').setTag('textBoxA');

  var pasteHandler = app.createServerChangeHandler('readTextbox');
  pasteHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);

  var clickButton=app.createButton("type anything and click here to get the textBoxValue")
                   .setId("PasteTest")
                   .addClickHandler(pasteHandler) 

  panel.add(textBoxA);
  panel.add(clickButton);
  app.add(panel);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(app);
}

function readTextbox(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  var boxValue=e.parameter.textBoxA;
  var butn = app.getElementById('PasteTest').setHTML(boxValue);
  return app;
}
```