# How to use data entered in panel in a Google Doc - GAS

Tags: variables, user-interface, google-apps-script, event-handling

First of all: this site has been a great help already to me, thnx a lot!

In a Google doc I am adding a vertical panel to assist the user in composing and sending a letter. I used the example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355789/ui-get-value-function-not-work-in-document-app) and it works fine showing the panel:

```
function onOpen() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(455).setTitle('User input')
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','25px')
  var label1 = app.createLabel('Your name please');
  var box1 = app.createTextBox().setId('Field1').setName('Field1');
  panel.add(label1)
  panel.add(box1)
  var pasteHandler = app.createServerChangeHandler('readTextbox');
  pasteHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  var clickButton=app.createButton('OK').setId('PasteTest').addClickHandler(pasteHandler) 
  panel.add(clickButton);
  app.add(panel);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(app);
//I want to arrive here only after a value is entered in the panel
//  ... follows more code ...
 }

function readTextbox(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  var boxValue=e.parameter.Field1;
//how to get this e.parameter values (more than one..) to the main function
  return app;
}
```

My question is: how to make the main function wait after 'showSidebar' until a value is entered?
Second question: how to use this input outside the handler, e.g. for writing in the document? I found a workaround by writing the fields to a spreadsheet within the handler, but that's not very elegant ;-)
Many thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by "main function"?  And also, in the context of a writing assistant wouldn't you prefer using a sidebar instead of a panel that masks almost everything?

Comment: In this case, onOpen() was the "main function". My idea was to continue with the user's input in onOpen(). Sany, however, suggests to continue the operation in readTextbox(). I'm gonna try that. As to your second question: i *am* using a sidebar and the result looks nice.

Comment: Oooops, sorry I didn't open the link so I misunderstood the panel concept!!!  Shame on me since I wrote the answer you referred to :-)

Comment: Yes you did and thnx for that ;-) By the way, what was the use of setWidth(455) since there seems to be nothing of that width?

Comment: at the time I wrote that one could choose the width of sidebars... now we can't anymore, so you can just ignore this line since the script will ignore it anyway ;-)

Comment: things are getting too easy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make the `onOpen()` function wait, but you don't need to.  You have a click handler and the readTextbox() function.  And you don't need to get the readTextbox() function to branch back to the onOpen() function.  If there are conditions that require branching to different functions depending on what the user does, then you can create a new function.

You can call a function from a function just by using it's name, and parenthesis after the name and a semicolon.

```
function readTextbox(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  var boxValue=e.parameter.Field1;

  anotherCoolFunction(boxValue);
//how to get this e.parameter values (more than one..) to the main function
  return app;
}

function anotherCoolFunction(someArg){
  Logger.log('Some Arg: ' + someArg);

}
```

In the above code, after the name is entered and the user clicks the button, the readTextBox function runs, then the `readTextBox()` function calls the `anotherCoolFunction(boxValue);` function and passes the variable boxValue to the `anotherCoolFunction()`.

You can verify that it works, by looking at the log.  Choose the View Menu, and the Logs menu item to display the Log output.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a new line of thought. I considered it a sub-routine but actually as long as you keep working with the handler it has become the main line indeed...